# Anybody knows more about the "modified trapezoidal rule" (quadrature)?

Tags: integration, quadrature

In the Abramowitz & Stegun book (Handbook of Mathematical Functions) there is an item number 25.4.4 called "modified trapezoidal rule" (quadrature). Can anybody point me to some more detailed publication(s) dealing with this sort of quadrature(s)? I need quadratures for evaluating an integral over the interval between two neighbouring grid points, which use integrand values not only at these two points but also at grid points located OUTSIDE the above interval.
Leszek

Comment: Have a look at  https://www.reading.ac.uk/maths-and-stats/-/media/project/uor-main/schools-departments/maths/documents/mohd-thesis.pdf?la=en&hash=FEA2F872AFCCB89700C05B816F83A8C3